# Dr. Watson Woes

Tags: windows-xp

A Windows XP box on my network gets slammed with memory exception errors from two of Microsoft's Dr. Watson debugger processes if the machine is left idle for more than 15 minutes in the Welcome screen. The messages pop up one after the other infinitely upon waking the computer forcing the user to reboot. The XP machine in question is fully updated to SP3 and all the recent hotfixes and updates are installed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: First. Windows XP?!? o.O Second, have you run a memory checker on this system?

Comment: There ARE times when a wipe/reload/replace are the best option.

Comment: LOL @ EEAA! Unfortunately, our customized case management software my company paid tens of thousands of dollars for was designed in 2005, so they want to milk every minute they can until they're forced to upgrade. Totally with you on that one! I will throw in my Hiren's Boot USB and see if I can come up with any memory issues, but this problem seems to only occur with Drwtsn32.exe and DWWIN.exe, and I have had no reports of blue-screens or any other indicators of a physical memory issue, but still worth it to check.

Comment: @TheCleaner I agree. I just wanted to exhaust all other options before having to run a clean install. But, if that's my only option, I suppose I'll have to bite the bullet.

Comment: This is still a physical machine?!? P2V it!